# Enclosing Bottom of Shed After Removing Animals

Tags: shed

My wife and I would like to prevent animals from living under our shed, as some of the enclosing wood came off previously and we believe there is now a skunk under there.

However, before we re-enclose the space I'd like to ensure that we don't trap any animals under the shed, and I'm wondering what our options might be?

Comment: fireworks: smoke bombs and firecrackers are widely available now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard approach is some sort of one-way door, usually made from wire mesh (hardware cloth) with springs or weights so it will push out from the inside to open. The situation can be complicated if there are baby skunks under there (if your skunk becomes highly visible trying to get back in, consider propping the door open for a day to allow relocation of the nest.)

Comment: If you think there are immobile babies in there, just wait until you no longer think so, or until the end of the mating season.   Then put in a one-way trap and leave it for a few weeks.  If you *don't* see mama trying to get in, you're good to seal it up.   I have always used professionals for this because of their knowledge of the particular animals' habits and their ability to determine what is happening from subtle clues that I don't know.   Just  dumbly (in my case) adding and removing trap doors is not effective.